# Keeping tub and shower clean, mildew-free

Tags: cleaning, bathroom

Is there a quick, daily routine to keep the tub and shower clean? A procedure after each use? I am also wondering how others use their shower curtains: do you keep it in/over the tub at all times (including baths) or only for showers?

Answer (score 3):

No, you will always have to clean your bathroom regularly with proper cleaners (that's why they exist), but you can reduce the needed frequency by using the water to rinse off obvious scum (dirt, soap, etc.) after use. Or you could just quickly wipe it down with cleaners every day. [Boom! Life hack!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dYn-z8RoZg&feature=youtu.be)

> I am also wondering how others use their shower curtains: do you keep it in/over the tub at all times (including baths) or only for showers?

Keep it where it is the most useful. You can determine where it is the most useful by taking a moment to visualize where the water may go, using your imagination to fill in the effect of certain laws of physics, such as gravity. Alternatively, you can do an experiment using a real shower and a shower curtain.

In showers you keep part on the inside, otherwise, as you can see, water runs on the bathroom floor. In baths unless you're splashing all over the place it just gets in the way on the inside. Generally two shower curtains are used: a plastic mildew resistant one for the inside, and a cloth nicer looking one for the outside. That's why both of these types of shower curtains are sold together in stores.

Answer (score 1):

The best cleaner I've found for bathroom scum is a mixture of vinegar and Dawn.  Dawn cuts oils really well and the vinegar kills the bacteria.  I read this somewhere before re-caulking around the tub and was surprised at how really well it worked.  If you're killing the bacteria regularly and getting rid of the oils, it should keep it cleaner.  I put it in a squirt bottle, let it sit for about 5 minutes, ran over it quickly with an old toothbrush and everything rinsed and wiped right away.

Comment: Use white vinegar and blue Dawn. The blue Dawn is specifically good because it contains no additives in addition to the detergent. When highly diluted, it washes and rinses without a trace. It has been recommended by manufacturers for washing delicate optics without damage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

1. You might want to get transparent plastic walls instead of a curtain (a solid "curtain" makes the process easier)
2. If you use shower gel or bathing lotion/salt, rinse the shower or tub clear when you´re done.
3. If you don´t have a window in your bathroom, give the humidity a few minutes to subside. If you have one, open it before step 4 and leave it open for five to ten minutes after step 5.
4. Use a window cleaner on the walls to reduce the amount of towels needed in step 5
5. Use a towel or two to dry the shower/tub/sink, the curtain, the walls and the silicone and rub the faucet clean.

You may need chemicals and scrub a while, maybe even replace the silicone, to get it in order in the beginning; but actually towels are all you need to *keep* it clean.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Leave a spray with a mixture of Bleach and water near the tub, spray in everything after you are finished in shower. Works for me.